# JS проверка на наличие слова в src картинки

Tags: javascript

Есть html элемент img, в нём есть src='', как проверить src на содержание определённого слова? например слова home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск подстроки в строке можно делать по-разному, вот два способа:

С помощью `.includes`

```
const string = "test test rest yest fest test";
const substring = "test";
string.includes(substring);
```

С помощью regexp:

```js
const string = "test test tes rest fest test";
const subsring = /test/;
string.match(substring)
```

.

Вот, как можно выполнить поиск по атрибуту:

```js
const src = document.querySelector("img").src;

const substr = /word/ // определенное слово

src.match(substr)
```

Comment: `src.match(substr)` не ?)

Comment: @АлексДанилин, спасибо, исправил.